# Can I use JQuery to check each image and display different div if it has no url?

Tags: jquery, foreach

I want to use JQuery to check to see if an image is available, and if not set its containing div to display:none and a different div in the same section to display:inline.

I'm not a guru at javascript and I know this code is wrong but can you suggest a fix?

Here is an example of my HTML and CSS, and the JQuery I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="content" >
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/IMG_0711a.JPG" alt="image"> </div>
    <div class="noimage"> </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="content" >
    <div class="image"> <img src="" alt="no image src"> </div>
    <div class="noimage"> </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="content" >
    <div class="image"> <img src="images/IMG_0711a.JPG" alt="image"> </div>
    <div class="noimage"> </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.noimage    {display:none;}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".content").each(function()       //for each class 'content'
    {      
    var $selection = $(this);
    if ($('.content .image img').attr('src') == '')    //if inner div called 'image' has image url equal to null
        {
        $".content .image".remove();            //hide the inner div 'image'
        $".content .noimage".show();            //show the inner div 'noimage'
        $".content .noimage".text("my text");   //add text to inner div 'noimage'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".content").each(function()  {      
    var $selection = $(this);
    if (!$('img', $selection).attr('src')) {
        $(".image", $selection).remove();            //hide the inner div 'image'
        $(".noimage", $selection).show().text("my text");            //show the inner div 'noimage'
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SmQj5/1/)